# Trying to install python ping module on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, module, ping

So I've got some python code that requires I "import ping". I tried using pip t install it but for whatever reason that wasn't working so I just downloaded the [zip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping/0.1). I extracted it and ran setup.py but I keep getting the error:

```
error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ping.py: Permission denied
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: did you try running a sudo?

Comment: ~~sudo pip install ping or sudo apt-get install ping?~~

Never mind got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via pip

```
sudo pip install ping
```

Via Python (manual) what you need !

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

You Need Admin rights